# how to write generate Fibonacci in python

Tags: python, generator, fibonacci, yield, function

```
def fib(a, b, f):
```

fib must generate (using yield) the generalized Fibonacci
sequence, a and b is first and second element. f is function to get the third element instead of a+b as normal Fibonacci sequence. Use take function(which show below) to test it.

my code is below

```
def fib(a, b, f):
    x = a
    y = b
    yield x
    x, y = y, f(x,y)
    fib(x,y,f)
```

I don't know what is wrong of my code, when I try to test it, it show
`"TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable"`

the test case is:

```
 take(5, fib(0, 1, lambda x, y: x - y))
```

It should out put:

```
[0, 1, -1, 2, -3]
```

and take function as i write is :

```
def take(n, iterable):
       x = []
    if n <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        for i in range (0,n):
            x.append(iterable[i])
        return x
```

Comment: `yield` returns a generator not an iterator.

Comment: Is `take (...)` **Python** function? More likely from **Haskell** ;)

Comment: @Anzel It's a function the OP defined himself.

Comment: @augurar, I know, I'm just being a little sarcastic ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means that generators do not support indexing, so `iterable[i]` fails.  Instead, use the `next()` function to get the next item from the iterator.

```
def take(n, iterable):
    x = []
    if n > 0
        itr = iter(iterable)     # Convert the iterable to an iterator
        for _ in range(n):       # Repeat n times
            x.append(next(itr))  # Append the next item from the iterator
    return x
```

Also, your `fib()` function will not work.  You should not recurse at the end of the function; instead write a loop that `yield`s a value each iteration.

```
def fib(a, b, f):
    x = a
    y = b
    while True:
        yield x
        x, y = y, f(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't index into the results coming from a generator function like `fib()`. This following avoids that by using `zip()` with a `range()` argument. `zip()` stops automatically when one of its arguments reaches then end.

```
def fib(a, b, f):
    x, y = a, b
    while True:
        yield x
        x, y = y, f(x, y)

def take(n, iterable):
    return [] if n <= 0 else [v for _, v in zip(range(n), iterable)]

print( take(5, fib(0, 1, lambda x, y: x-y)) )
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, -1, 2, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci simplest method you'll ever come across:

```
a , b =0 , 1

for n in range(100):#any number 
    print(a)
    a = a + b
    print (b)
    b = b + a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)


n = int(input("enter the number: "))
for i in range(n):
    print(fibo(i))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?